# How can I create VBA which creates a pivot table only if it doesn't already exist

Tags: vba, excel, pivot, pivot-table

I am just learning VBA so not completely familiar with it yet.

I would like to creates a pivot table with a dynamic range only if the pivot table doesnt already exist. If the table already exists then the pivot jut needs to refresh.

so far I have this:

```
Sub CreatingPivot()
Dim PCache As PivotCache, LastRow As Long, pt As PivotTable
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = Sheets("Pivot")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
 Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=1, SourceData:=Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address)
     Worksheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Pivot"
    ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
 Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PCache, TableDestination:=Range("A1"), TableName:="PivotTable1")

    Else
       Sheets("Pivot").RefreshTable
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
Dim PivTbl as PivotTable

On Error Resume Next
    Set PivTbl = Sheets("Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
On Error Goto 0
    If PivTbl Is Nothing Then
        'Create pivot table
    End If
'Do your stuff
```

**EDIT FOR OP COMMENT/FOLLOW-ON Q**

Refresh the PivotTable not the Worksheet

```
Dim PivTbl As PivotTable

    Set PivTbl = Sheets("Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable1")

    PivTbl.RefreshTable
```

Comment: I have tried this but i am still unable to get the pivot to refresh when the pivot already exists. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @Julie Routley - see Edit to answer.